# Url manager and Htaccess in Yii1

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii1.x

I have url like this:

> www.studyenglish/index.php?r=site/lesson&act=read&id=1

I would like change to be:

> www.studyenglish/site/lesson/read

I have added this script in url manager config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
       ....
       'showScriptName'=>false,
        ....
    ),
```

and add this script in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

But it only work in url like this:

> www.studyenglish/index.php?r=site/lesson

to be:

> www.studyenglish/site/lesson

So, how to change this url

> www.studyenglish/index.php?r=site/lesson&act=read&id=1

to be

> www.studyenglish/site/lesson/read

Hopefully someone can help.
Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

In **UrlManager** there are **rules** , you can define your own rules.
your UrlManager may look like this.

```
'urlManager' => array(
'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => array(
        'gii' => 'gii/index',
        'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => 'gii/<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        'site/lesson/<act:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'site/lesson'
        //
```

This will call **actionLesson** in **SiteController**, which is supposed to get two parameter .

You method should look something like this.

```
public function actionLesson($act,$id){
    //
}
```

Comment: I get error Property "CUrlManager.routes" is not defined.
I added this script in main.php -> log->routes ..

Comment: I have edited the answer, to show you where line goes exactly. Also remove your answer , that is not an answer by definition but just explanation of problem. Edit the question if want

Answer (score 1):

Change your .htaccess to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

And add proper rules in URL manager.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `urlManager` like:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'=>array(),
        ),
```

and your `.htaccess` like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```